# UTF-8 Characters handled differently on production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, ruby-on-rails-4, utf-8, thinking-sphinx

On my Local machine I can search for "Härtefälle" which will result in the following URL:

### Development

http://myapp.dev/de/incoming?q=H%E4rtef%E4llen

I can submit as many times as I want, it always looks correct:

[image: correct]

Info:

```
Mac OSX 10.9.5
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
thinking-sphinx (3.1.1)
rails (4.0.4)
/usr/local/Cellar/sphinx/2.2.4
```

`locale` command:

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

### Production

However on my production environment when I enter the search term and click "Apply", I get the following result:

[image: weird1]

curiously when I keep pressing Apply, the term gets bigger and weirder, but somehow the search engine is still able to see the term "Härtefällen" behind this weird `HÃÂÃ¢ÂÂ¬rtefÃÂÃ¢ÂÂ¬llen`because the corresponding search result is displayed:

[image: weird2]

[image: weird3]

Info:

```
Debian 7.0
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
rails (4.0.4)
thinking-sphinx (3.1.1)
Package: sphinxsearch Version: 2.0.4-1.1
```

`locale` command:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

### Bottomline

The only thing I do in my controller is unescaping the search params `H%E4rtef%E4llen`:

```
# TODO: Somehow `René` turns into `Ren\xE4`
params[:q] = params[:q].encode('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-15') rescue nil
```

Now how do I get the sane behaviour on production? Please let me know if I can provide any more relevant information.

Comment: Can you tell us which versions of Ruby, Rails, Sphinx and Thinking Sphinx you're using (for both environments)?

Comment: Also, I wouldn't modify params (generally), but instead capture the modified version as a variable instead, and use that variable as needed. This should avoid the same string being modified for each request.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I did add the relevant information

Comment: May be it's the locale ? On Debian, you can check with the ````locale```` command. It should give you something like ````LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8````. I don't know Mac OSX but the command should be the same.

Comment: @FredPerrin I did update my question with the output from `locale`. It does differ but I don't know if `en_US.UTF-8` causes any problems.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment wasn't clear and complete. It doesn't matter if it differ between prod and dev (it's not the same database). But I think you should check the locale of your database (defined when you created it) and the config in Rails (database.yml). The OS is already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong:

1. I have a form which I use to POST data to the server
2. The server redirects to a new URL with GET Parameters
3. In Step `1` the characters are properly encoded, but for step `2` where I form a new URL I need to escape the URL using `URI.encode`:

   URI.encode(myURL)

So that e.g. `ö` turns into `%C3%B6`